# "None of these files exist" when try to use vertical icons reac native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-vector-icons

I have installed React Native Vector Icons, I have changed the `android/app/build.gradle adding  apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"`.

When I try to import icons in the file (for example):

```
import React from 'react';
import {StatusBar, StyleSheet, Text, FlatList, View, TextInput, Button} from 'react-native';
import { Ionicons } from "react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons";

const HomeScreen = () => {
    return (
        <View style={styles.page}>
            <Ionicons name="ios-camera-reverse" />
        </View>
    );
};

export default HomeScreen;
```

**then I got an error (screen):**

[image]

I have installed React Native Vector Icons, I have changed the android/app/build.gradle adding  **apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change Import:

```
import Ionicons from "react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons";
```

check default import here: https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons/blob/master/MaterialIcons.js